# cordova webview is not saving passwords on form submit

Tags: android, wordpress, cordova, android-webview

I have an android app with CordovaActivity which loads a login page for wordpress website using loadUrl("loginurl"), when the user enters his credentials for the first time a prompt asks for password remembering, however when the user closes the app and reopen it the password field is cleared and just got the username remembered.
 when using the native android webview for the same site the password is saved correctly but I need to use cordova in my app, any idea how to make CordovaWebview remember wordpress login password?

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
    LOGIN_URL = getString(R.string.site_url) + "/wp-login.php";
    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml

    loadUrl(LOGIN_URL);

}
```

Comment: If you think it's an issue, report it on http://issues.cordova.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 months I found a solution, for some reason when you use webview and load the WP login page, wordpress clears the password filed if you are already logged in instead of redirecting you to the home page, the solution was to not load the login page on application start up and just load the home page and put a login widget.